# char [] and sprintf segmentation fault

Tags: c, char, segmentation-fault, printf

Here is a stripped version of my program. I don't see why I am getting segmentation fault here.

```
....
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char quit = 0;
    char buffer[100];
    ...
    while (quit == 0) {
        sprintf(buffer,"%s",get_timer_ticks(&mytimer));
        // puts(buffer);
...
}
```

Edit: By the way, get_timer_ticks returns Uint32.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use

```
sprintf(buffer,"%u",get_timer_ticks(&mytimer));
```

`%s` expects string, not integer. Since some random integer is unlikely to be a valid pointer to something resembling NULL-terminated string, SEGFAULT occurs.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking `sprintf()` to format a string and put it into `buffer`. As a result, it's treating your unsigned integer like a pointer -- and likely a very bad pointer, hence the segfault. Change your `%s` to `%u` to request it to format an unsigned integer instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to interpret an integer as a string. This causes printf to try to read a string from an address with the number that `get_timer_ticks` happens happen to return. There's likely that there is no valid string at this address.

Answer (score 0):

The `%s` format specifier is for C-style strings, but `get_timer_ticks` returns a Uint32. The value returned is very unlikely to make sense to `sprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `%u` instead of `%s` in sprintf.